# HTML - Making proper use of DIV tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

The following is a sample of my code -

```
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="red">
     <div class='log' style="background-color:white;width:auto; margin:0; padding:15px 20px">
     <marquee scrollamount="6" scrolldelay="100"><font size='4' color='black'>Test</marquee>
    <hr>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run it, I can see extra div space, Is there any possible way to remove the extra div space?
Thanks.

Comment: Where's you're closing `</div>` tag? Also, the [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) tag is obselete. Thought it may work, it's use in newer applications is highly discouraged.

Comment: tried add `margin: 0; padding: 0` to `body` element?

Comment: 1. you never closed your div tag. is it meant to surround the marquee tag? 2. what do you mean "extra div space"? you've added padding to your div, is that the space you're talking about?

Comment: FYI you are using obsolete features, including `bgcolor`, `<font>` and.. `<marquee>`!?

Comment: Sorry guys.. Accidently pasted the older code from my program. Need to update it a second

Comment: As @George mentions, you are using several features that are obselete and that have been obselete for some time now. I'd highly suggestion that you visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web and bookmark this as a reference to use when completing future development. The information in this index provides a solid HTML, CSS and JavaScript foundation on which to build on.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding.

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="red">
        <div class="log" style="background-color:white;width:auto; margin:0;" >
            <marquee scrollamount="6" scrolldelay="100"><font size='4' color='black'>Test</marquee>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top and bottom padding to remove this "extra" space that you speak of. If however, you mean the body, no, there's no way to shorten it's height.

```
<div class='log' style="background-color:white;width:auto; margin:0; padding:15px 0px">
```

Also, you forgot to close your div tag.